# How to remove all of the formatting from some HTML

Tags: php, phpquery

I have the following from a website which I am scraping but unfortunately the content also contains some font tags and could possibly contain other inline formatting in the future. I'm using PHPQuery to do this but a PHP only solution also works.

```
<p>
<font
color="#cc0000">
    <font
    color="#000000">Content</font>
        </font>
</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>
    <font
    color="#cc0000">Content I wish to keep but font should be removed</font>
</p>
<p>
    <font
    color="#cc0000">Content I wish to keep but font should be removed</font>
</p>
<p>
    <font
    color="#cc0000">Content I wish to keep but font should be removed</font>
</p>
<p>
    <font
    color="#cc0000">Content I wish to keep but font should be removed</font>
</p>
<p>
    <font
    color="#000000">Content I wish to keep but font should be removed</font>
</p>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: PHPQuery uses JQuery style selectors hence why I included the jquery tag.

Comment: why don't you use strip_tags?

Comment: Copy and paste through notepad from user normal view

Comment: @Robert http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9970552#9970552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags);

```
strip_tags ($str, '<p><div>');
```

this line will remove all the tags but P and DIV You can add more alowable tags to second argument.

Example from php.net

```
 <?php
 $text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
 echo strip_tags($text);
 echo "\n";

 // Allow <p> and <a>
 echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
 ?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the content is in a variable:

```
$content = strip_tags( $str, '<p><div>' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The phpQuery way might look like this:

```
while($font = $dom->find('font')->eq(0)){
  if(0 === $font->size()) break; // to prevent a strange phpquery bug
  $font->replaceWith($font->text());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting to see how it would of been done in PhpQuery.